# Time axis in 24 hour clock

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to be able to display time using the 24 hour clock. When I generate a time axis, the default display is in the 12 hour clock. So far, I haven't found a way of changing this. Can this be done?

Comment: Please add some code showing your problem.

Answer (score 3):

(Without seeing any code its difficult to suggest an exact answer)

But you could use the following to create 24 hour time format :

```
var format = d3.time.format("%H:%M");
```

[see the d3 time formatting docs here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format)

Comment: Cheers, I just used tickFormat in the end and the time format as you suggested.

Comment: @user1440303 make sure you accept answers for **all** the questions you ask .. if you have no idea what im talking about [click here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170679) for an explanation